# Make a measurement of a signal at a specific time rate in Simulink

Tags: matlab, controller, simulink, measurement, rate

I have a Simulink model with a controller that inputs a command in a system.

The controller gives its input based on the state measurements given by the system, and I want to simulate that the system has only access to measurements at a specific rate, 1/Ts (with Ts the sampling time). Which would imply that during one Ts the controller holds a constant input.

However I would like the system dynamics to be computed using an accurate solver using variable step-size.

Right now, I managed to make it work when using a solver with a fixed step-size. For instance when the sample rate Ts is 100 the fixed step size, I have simply added a block with this Matlab function after the controller and before the system:

```
function [old_input, output, new_counter] = fcn(new_input, old_input, counter)
if counter < 99
    new_counter = counter + 1;
    output = old_input;
else
    new_counter = 0;
    output = new_input;
    old_input = new_input;
end
```

Where I initialize the counter variable to 99.

Is there a way to have a similar result when using a variable step-size.

Comment: Another way may be to have multiple rates in your model using rate transition blocks.

Comment: You need to spend some time learning how Simulink works, perhaps starting with the basic examples at [Sample Times in Systems](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/managing-sample-times-in-systems.html).  Simulink inherently allows you to do what you are trying to do with your code by setting block sample times appropriately.